# Represetable etale covering of diagonal embeddings of algebraic spaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be an etale map of algebraic spaces (i.e, $X$ and $Y$ have representable etale coverings $U^{\cdot}$ and $V^{\cdot}$ so that there is an etale map $h:U\rightarrow V$ induces $f$). Is it true that $U^{\cdot}\times_{V^{\cdot}}U^{\cdot}$ is a representable etale covering of $X\times_Y X$? Why? Why not?:)

Comment: Why not? All these properties are stable under fiber products.

Comment: Hmm. So what is the answer? Can you add more details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is. $f$ doesn't even need to be etale.
It follows from Knutson's proof of the existence of fiber product in the category of algebraic spaces (II 1.5).